# Data persistence due to RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Y.JS)

Tags: javascript, frontend, tiptap

I am using Y.JS with hocuspocus and tiptap editor and facing an issue with persisting my data on my app and it gets triggered due to the following error.

```
sync.js:86 Caught error while handling a Yjs update RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Transaction.js:307:38
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:307:30)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
    at cleanupTransactions (Transaction.js:370:9)
readSyncStep2 @ sync.js:86
readSyncMessage @ sync.js:121
applySyncMessage @ MessageReceiver.ts:70
apply @ MessageReceiver.ts:31
onMessage @ HocuspocusProvider.ts:561
```

Can anyone help?

Tried switching off a bunch of things but the error still appears.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise it is probably impossible to help, but at least unlikely somebody can or will help, and the question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug in Y.js](https://github.com/yjs/yjs/issues/522).  The problem is that `cleanupTransactions()` is a recursive function, so if there are a large number of cleanups to do, it overflows the call stack and crashes.

I've been sitting on a fork of `github.com/yjs/yjs` that fixes the bug for several months.  Seeing your question motivated me to [finally open a PR on `yjs/yjs` that fixes this bug](https://github.com/yjs/yjs/pull/523).  Drop a comment on the PR or preferably the [associated discussion issue #522](https://github.com/yjs/yjs/issues/522) to encourage the maintainers to merge my PR or implement an alternative fix.

Without some fix for this issue, there is currently no way to use Y.js for large documents.  I happen to think my PR is quite elegant in its simplicity :-), but the maintainers may want to take a different approach.

(Brief aside: because the recursion is a tail call, the browser Javascript engine actually could optimize it away, but the most common browser, Chrome, [doesn't implement tail call optimization](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5516876633341952).  You'll notice the bug does not happen in Safari because Safari/WebKit actually does optimize away tail call recursion correctly.)